# How to change default superuser password for jasper report server?

Tags: jasperserver

How to change default superuser and jasperadmin passwords in Jasper report server?

Thanks

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v60/configuring-user-password-options & http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844732/reset-jasperadmin-password

Comment: You can also look at JasperReports-Server-Security-Guide

Comment: Thanks Alex. Found it.

Comment: You are welcome :)